# How can "while (true)" can be avoided in this piece of code?

Tags: c#

Let me rephrase my question.

Please consider the following piece of code:

```
while (true)
{
    Console.Write("Please enter something ");
    userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userInput))
    {
        break;
    }
    collection.Add(userInput);
}
```

How can it be changed to avoid using `while (true)`?

Comment: Code smell is subjective, and standards are too many to chose from. Can you re-phrase this question into something that can get objective answers?

Comment: Yes, I will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd rather see this construct:

```
string userInput;
bool again;
do
{
    Console.Write("Please enter something ");
    userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    if (again = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(userInput))
        collection.Add(userInput);
} while (again);
```

Comment: I have came up with a similar solution with the difference being that I didn't use a variable (`again`) as you did. Is it  a problem when you use the same conditional statement in different pieces of code?

Comment: @menteith Checking a boolean is a very efficient operation and I think it gives clear intention on what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you have `while (true)` now is because the initial part of your loop body doesn't fit in the loop condition. You can therefore avoid `while (true)` by refactoring that into a function.

```
bool TryGetUserInput(out string userInput) {
    Console.Write("Please enter something ");
    userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(userInput);
}

...

string userInput;
while (TryGetUserInput(out userInput))
    collection.Add(userInput);
```

Comment: This is indeed the cleanest way in case the original construct has to be avoided at all. Especially with C#7.0 local functions and `out var`.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
do
{
    Console.Write("Please enter something ");
    userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userInput))
    {
        collection.Add(userInput);
    }
}while(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userInput));
```

Comment: This doesn't behave the same as the OP's code. It continues as long as the input is null or empty. The OP's code continues as long as the input is *not* null or empty.

Comment: @hvd is right here.

Comment: @menteith The morale of the story - don't try to avoid a perfectly valid construct which is easy to read, easy to follow, does the necessary logic w/o artificial `bool` variables or duplicate condition checks.

Comment: @IvanStoev That's a wonderful advice! As a newbie I often tend to double check whether my code is good enough, even at simple things as described in my post. So, clarity comes first.

Comment: @hvd thanks, i miss a ! inside the while condition

Answer (score 0):

It has already been mentioned that code smell is subjective which is true, but in this case there is a simple argument against using `while(true)`.

You're missing an opportunity to be expressive in your code. Consider:

```
while(true)
```

What does this tell you about the code? we know nothing other than potentially this code will run indefinitely.

Now consider:

```
while(inputIsNotEmpty)
```

Immediately we know the proceeding block or statement will run until the input is empty. Which will save the reader of code (mostly yourself) a bit of time rather than having to hunt down the exit condition.

This is how I would avoid using `while(true)` in this particular case.

```
do{
   Console.Write("Please enter something ");
   input = Console.ReadLine(); 
   if (inputIsNotEmpty(input)) collection.Add(input);
  } while (inputIsNotEmpty(input);

...

bool inputIsNotEmpty(string input) => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(input);
```